# $\int e^x\sin x\ dx$: how many substitutions?

Tags: calculus, integration-by-parts

I got the answer of $-\frac12e^x\cos x$ after substituting twice. Do I always have to substitute twice for all simple integration-by-parts problems?

Comment: How many times do you have to take the derivative of $sin x$ to get $sin x$ again?

Comment: By substitution you mean integration by parts?

Comment: @DrHAL 4 times, but you should only apply it twice.  ;)

Comment: you do not have to integrate twice for all integration by parts problems, but you do need to in this case.  There is a way to do it using complex numbers and no integration by parts.

Comment: @SimpleArt I'm not really asking, just trying to make him see by himself :)

Comment: I guess how do I know when to stop integrating before computing? @DrHAL I see what you mean!

Comment: @asdfajigs Once you reach the function you are integrating initially, naturally you can stop so you can substitute your original integral by some "M" and then you would have M + "some other stuff" = -M (for this case, with sine). So you can isolate and so on and so forth...

Comment: By the way, the answer you have is not correct.  You have dropped something.

Comment: None. This integral usually isn't done with substitution. And ... your answer is incorrect. You can check this by differentiating: $\frac{d}{dx} ( - \frac{1}{2} e^x \cos x) \ne e^x \sin x$.

Comment: yeah i accidentally used wrong U @HansEngler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\int e^x  \sin{x} dx=\frac{1}{2} \int e^x((\sin{x}-\cos{x})+(\cos{x}+\sin{x}))dx$$

Then, use $$\int e^x(f(x)+f'(x))dx=e^xf(x)+c$$